# How to grab an object from a list within a list

Tags: python, list, class

I have a main list called `productInv` which contains many sublists. Each sublist has 4 objects, `[name, units, cost, price]`. I need a way to grab the `cost` and `units` from each sublist within the main list using a `for` loop.

So far I have:

```
for prod in productInv:
    itemCost = prod[2]
```

This is giving me an error: `object does not support indexing`.

Comment: So what type of object *is* `prod`? Are we supposed to guess? You call it a *"sublist"*, but it's clearly not a `list`.

Comment: Can you provide a clearer or runnable answer? (as in give us code so we can see what context is happening around what you're asking, I.E. put prod initial value in, etc),

Comment: show us the content of `productInv`

Comment: You can debug this stuff pretty quickly yourself by using the `dir(prod)` command (or if you're not in interactive mode, `print dir(prod)`) to see information about the object.

Comment: obv, prod is not a list. otherwise it would be indexable.

Comment: yes. prod is supposed to be the sub-list in the main list. prod = [name, unit, cost, price]. prod has no initial value, that's just the term i've decided to use for my for loop.

Comment: rather than exchanging long list of comments, please print out the `productInv` you have so that we can understand the beast better.

Comment: The `repr` may look right, but `type(prod)` (or, for that matter, *the word you cut from the start of the traceback*) will tell you what's really going on.